# Как осуществить действие только над одним элементом из набора jQuery?

Tags: jquery, списки, img, загрузка, jscript

```
$(".img_list").on("click", "li", function() {
  var li = $(this); 
  $("#loader").click();

  $(document).on('response', function(e, data) {
   var data = '<img src="/img/' + data.filename + '/>';
   li.html(data);
  });
});
```

По клику на элемент списка `li` в него загружается изображение.

Проблема: при загрузке второго (третьего, и т.д.) изображения в следующий элемент списка всем предыдущим загруженным изображениям в предыдущих `li` присваивается тот же адрес `src`, т.е. вместо разных изображений в разных элементах `li` везде отображается одно изображение, загруженное последним.

Попытки обращаться по `id` к элементам списка, присваивать `data.filename` переменной, которую приводить к `null` после каждого добавления изображения, проблему не решили.

Прошу посоветовать, как сделать правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Клик по новому `li` не сбросит обработчиков с прошлых `li`. Можно попробовать так:

```
var li = null;
$(".img_list").on("click", "li", function() {
    li = $(this); 
    $("#loader").click();
});
$(document).on('response', function(e, data) {
    if(li != null){
        var data = '<img src="/img/' + data.filename + '/>';
        li.html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: В первом варианте всё заработало, спасибо! Последующие редакции не проверял.

Comment: В первой редакции event `response` тоже навешивался лишние разы. Не смертельно, но небрежно.

Comment: если до первого ответа успеть кликнуть на следующий пункт, то загрузится оба раза во второй

Comment: @teran, верно. Не хватает информации о том что такое `$("#loader")`, что бы правильно передать параметры. А можно просто блокировать нажатия, до выполнения `response`.